# Get Parent's Parent HTML in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a few tags, here is the code

```
<p class="post-meta-ab"><span><a href="#">Diamond Burs set of 30 pcs A-24</a></span>

    <br /><span><i class="icon-circle"></i>Details: Diamond Burs set of 30 pcs very useful assorted shapes</span>

    <br /> <span><i class="icon-circle"></i>Shipping Weight: 100 gms</span>

    <br /><span><i class="icon-circle"></i>Price: &#8364; 2.50</span>

    <br /> <span><i class="icon-circle"></i>Quantity: <input type="text" style="width:20px" maxlength="100" name="a1" id="a1" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Add" style="margin-top:-8px" class="btn btn-danger" name="asubmit" id="a1sub" /></span>

</p>
```

My question is I am using

```
var productname = $(this).parent().html();
```

to get the details, but the details are coming of the  tag, I want to get the tag of the span's tag i.e "p" tag's html.

EDIT X: I want to get the data inside the input type="text" is it possible?

EDIT X2: I am using this now

```
    $(this).parent().parent().text()+$(this).parents('p').find('input:text').val()
```

it tends to work, ok last thing I want to do is, Put space after each details, example put space after shipping weight, put space after price and so on.

Comment: In your jQuery, what does `this` target?

Comment: this is referring to what here

Comment: "This" is the submit button.

Answer (score 4):

### How to get the parent's parent

To get the parent's parent you can simply call the `parent()` method on the parent:

```
$(this).parent().parent();
```

Alternatively you can use [jQuery's `closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(this).closest('p');
```

Here's a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/EUYxh/) which shows both in use when initially targeting `i.icon-circle`.

To get the text, you can then simply call [jQuery's `text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$(this).closest('p').text();
```

### How to get the text input's value

As per an edit to the question, to pull the value of the text input you can either use:

```
$(this).closest('p').find('input[type="text"]').val();
```

Or, as the input has an `id` of "a1" (which is always unique), you can just use:

```
$('#a1').val();
```

### How to put a space between the values

As per a further edit to the question, to put a space between the result you'd simply add it in using `... + " " + ...`, like so:

```
...closest('p').text() + " " + $(this).closest('p')...
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the data inside input type="text"?

Comment: @Ankur for that you can simply call `$(this).closest('p').find('input[type="text"]').val()`. Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/EUYxh/1/) which alerts the value of the text input (which I've hardcoded to "Hello, world!"). :)

Comment: I don't know why, but it is not working, it is displaying "undefined".

Comment: @Ankur I modified my comment, I missed a method out, sorry. Please check it again. Alternatively, however, as your input has an ID you could simply target it on that using `$('#a1').val()`.

Comment: @Ankur I've now modified my answer to reflect what I've said in the comments, too. :)

Comment: I am using this currently, $(this).parent().parent().text()+$(this).parents('p').find('input:text').val(), it tends to work, ok last thing I want to do is, Put space after each details, example put space after shipping weight, put space after price and so on.

Comment: @Ankur I'm not sure what you mean, this seems to be an extension of the question you originally asked. If you have a different question to ask than the one you originally posted then please accept an answer on this one and create a new question. -- It's worth noting that `closest()` is much faster than `parents()`, which is why I didn't use this in my answer: http://jsperf.com/parents-vs-closest-vs-id

Comment: @Ankur I've modified my answer to answer this new edit to your question. If you have any further questions which are different to your original question, please create a new question.

Comment: Donelly What should I do to get the first span element, I am trying to get each span and put space between them, I want to get this "Diamond Burs set of 30 pcs A-24", so I am trying to do is span + " " + span . . .

Comment: You can use `each()` to loop through each span: `$(this).closest('p').find('span').each({ alert($(this).text()); });`

Comment: I am trying to put everything in a variable, please tell me as it is not working var productname=$(this).closest('p').find('span').each({ $(this).text() + " "; });

Comment: You'd benefit from jQuery's interactive tutorial available at http://try.jquery.com, otherwise you're going to end up constantly asking questions.

Comment: I would just like to know the answer about query for .each as I am taking it in one variable. please help me.

Comment: Can you tell me how to scan the span one by one? please help

Comment: Please try the jQuery interactive tutorial. It will answer all your questions. If you still need help afterwards then start a new question. Your initial question was "how can I get the parent's parent in jQuery", and you're now asking a completely different question which will not help future users who get here through searching.

Comment: I started a new question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244336/get-data-from-multiple-span-using-jquery please look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) along with [.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML) if you want the html including `<p>...</p>`

```
$(this).closest('p')[0].outerHTML
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the data inside input type="text"?

Comment: @Ankur `$(this).siblings('input:text').val()`

Comment: Can you tell me how to scan each span one by one?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$(this).parent().parent().text();`

Comment: Is it possible to get the data inside input type="text"?

Comment: Yes... For that you can use .val() function.. For example, to get value of textbox having the id "a1", use $('#a1').val();

Comment: Also, if you wish to get value of each of the textboxes, you can use $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="text"]').val();

Comment: Personally I'd prefer using ID or class to get the values.. As you have already given the textbox ID a1, you can directly use the code provided earlier by me..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(this).closest('p').find('input:text').val();
```

or

```
$(this).parents('p').find('input:text').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

To know who the parent is or isn't you would have needed to tell us what is **$(this)**. Since you didn't here goes the code to get the value of your edit field.

```
alert($(".post-meta-ab").find("#a1").attr("value"));
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/hYhT6/

**EDIT**
Now we know who &(this) is... :-) I would go with the sieblings and not parent as you intially. In this case if you use parent you will have to then do some traversing so why not do it directly from the current location.

**One more edit**
A solution has been accepted but nevertheless here is my last take at it.
The prev() method would come handier; like this:

```
$("#a1sub").click(function() {
   alert($(this).prev().attr("value"));
})
```

And the [updated working fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/KbrvL/)