# Get data from multiple span using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently getting data on click of submit button, the html code is as follows:

```
<p class="post-meta-ab">
    <span>
        <a href="#">Diamond Burs set of 30 pcs A-24</a>
    </span><br />

    <span>
        <i class="icon-circle"></i>
        Details: Diamond Burs set of 30 pcs very useful assorted shapes
    </span><br />

    <span>
        <i class="icon-circle"></i>
        Shipping Weight: 100 gms
    </span><br />

    <span>
        <i class="icon-circle"></i>
        Price: &#8364; 2.50
    </span><br />

    <span>
        <i class="icon-circle"></i>
        Quantity: 
        <input type="text" style="width:20px" maxlength="100" name="a1" id="a1" />        
        <input type="submit" value="Add" style="margin-top:-8px" class="btn btn-danger" name="asubmit" id="a1sub" />
    </span>
</p>
```

I am getting the span data using the following jquery code:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    var productname = $(this).parent().parent().text() + $(this).parents('p').find('input:text').val();
    alert(productname); 
});
```

Now I am getting the span data, but I want space after each `span` tag, please help me regarding the same.

Comment: It already has space here- http://jsfiddle.net/stackrahul/WSdTw/, What is your exact problem?

Comment: change <br /> for <br>

Comment: I want a method by which I can scan each span tag one by one and put a space between them, I want to use this method only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
var alldata = "";
$('span').each(function(){
    var $span = $(this);        
    var spanTxt = $span.text();
    alldata += spanTxt + " ";     
}); 
alert(alldata);
});
```

Here all data has all the spans text

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WqYFV/11/)

Here i have used some extra variable for showing current span their text for understanding, you can loose them up if you want

Answer (score 0):

Had to do intense research, finally found a solution, this is it.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input[type=submit]').click(function(i){
      var txt="";
      txt=txt + "\n" + $(this).text();
      });
      txt= txt + $(this).parents('p').find('input:text').val();
      alert(txt);
          });
      return false;
    });
```